# SAML v2 forms auth

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I am wanting to do forms based auth using samlv2

I've done a large amount of research also looked at the source code for simplesamlphp

It seems as thought all that is needed when doing this aside from the actual saml request hidden inputs/values is to post the username & passwords with name=username and name=password?

Or am I missing something?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In reality I didn't understand how SAML worked to start with so I was trying to do something that I didn't need to.

Yes it is possible to do a forms based saml auth but most cases its probably not required.

I used the standard SAML 2.0 AUTH.

It may seem weird at first to how this works, how secure it is and how you validate the data, but I will be posting some thorough examples on my blog to be blog.elijahbate.me and in my github @ebyte23

Elijah